# How can I know last named of my file on linux which i changed by mistake...?

Tags: linux, putty

I am using linux server to host my site which is having cent os . By mistakely I changed the name of my file in putty where all files are shown by just cliking on it. I dont know what was the original name of file. Now I want the last modified name of its own. How can I retrive it.

eg file name :UpdateUser.php(I dont know what was name but here I am mentioning for your understanding)
(Mistakely) changed to: gup.php
now I want to do is gup.php to UpdateUser.php back or else I would say is there any command which undo changes done recently

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check mv command in your bash_history file.

Comment: Alternatively use your shells history by pressing the cursor up key which allows you to "walk through" the history of commands you executed.

Comment: how can i open bash_history file?

Comment: Type `history | grep mv`. Don't open the file unless necessary.

Comment: I have done this through command I have done this through putty@arkascha

Comment: after executiong i got the output as 
1031  history | grep mv @evert

Comment: Try `history 1000 | grep mv` to grep through the last 1000 commands you executed.

Comment: yogi - I don't understand what you are saying your did in PuTTY that changed a name by "clicking on it"?? PuTTY is a text terminal, I'm confused about the description of "clicking on it". While there may very well be some record in your bash history file, it would help to understand further what you are saying you did to change the file name.  In a text terminal, you can click on file names all you want with a mouse, but nothing is going to change??

Comment: actually by mistakenly i changed the name of file now i want original name but unfortunately i dont remember original name of it

Comment: @yogi *"i changed the name of file "* How did you change the name? `mv`? `cp` followed by `rm`? **How?**

Comment: file name was changed by clicking right mouse in putty protocols